# Bergman space on the unit disc

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}) \cap L^p(\mathbb{D})$ a complete space? Thank you very much. I think I have shown that it is a complete space for $p = 2$.

Comment: Yes, for $p=2$ the space $H(\mathbb{D}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{D})$ is a Hilbert space. The proof is not trivial though.

Comment: This should be tagged complex analysis.